# Pip upgrade to version 20 is now requiring 19?

Tags: python, pip

I've upgraded pip with 'pip install -U pip`

When `pip` is now run it fails with:

```
$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3251, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3264, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==19.3.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I'm on python 3.7.5

How can I resolve this? I already went and deleted pip and reinstalled it, but the same error occurs.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6399

Comment: @nicomp Yes, that's it.